# constrain for uiimageview to keep aspect ratio and expand based on device size

Tags: ios, uiimageview, constraints

i have this problem in 2 projects.Normally, profile image is displayed in circle like

[image]

and this is ok for iphone5 size.problem raises on bigger devices.like

[image]

as you can see size of profile imageview, it looks small compare to cover image.if i let it increase based on outer image then xocde ignores the aspect ratio constrains which results in non cricular profile imageview

here's current constrains image

[image]

any suggestion how should i handle it?

**Update**
here's result if i set constrain on profile imageview to increase with ratio to background image.

[image]

asks for y of image view,as i want it to be center so i sets fixed hight = 68 in hopes that xcode will break this constrain to keep aspect ratio, result

[image]

so if i remove hight = 68 and add constrain like width.

[image]

result

[image]

Comment: You have a fixed `width` and `height` constraint of `68`, which results image 1 & 2 having the same size

Comment: i also wrote "if i let it increase based on outer image then xocde ignores the aspect ratio constrains which results in non cricular profile imageview"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select your image view and it's super view together and give `equal width constraint`,

then select that `equal width constraint` from `size inspector`, and reduce its `multiplier` until you get your desired width!

Now select your image view and give `aspect ratio` constraint!

And finally give position constraint for x and y position!

In your case `center x` and `center y` with it's super view I think!

And your `imageview` will increase or decrease with device width and will remains square always!

And You should set dynamic `corner radius`(half of width or height of your imageview) in `layoutSubviews` method of tableviewcell's class as you need rounded imageview and your size is dynamic!

Comment: question updated, check results.or let me know if i did something wrong?

Comment: now if your height and width is dynamic then your corner radius also must be dynamic!!

Comment: i tried to log imageview frame in awakeFromNibl.they were same as in cell.so how do i find that ios did apply constrain and now i should  use imageview.frame.size.height / 2

Comment: you should do this in your `cellforrowatindexpath` if you are using tableview!

Comment: yes i'm using tableview and same frame numbers.and no effect.

Comment: no effect even doing it just before returning cell,

Comment: you have to do it after your cell is completely loaded not before! because after autolayout your size will be different !

Comment: yes but how?.cell don't have viewdidappear.otherwise i won't be problem..

i tried [cell layoutSubviews]; and then make image circular no effect. :'(

Comment: Iplement `layoutSubviews` in your tableview's cell's class and do it in this method! and don't forget to call `[super layoutSubViews]` first !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the height and width as constants, set equal width constraints between the background image and the profile image:

[image: Choose equal widths]

And then select the profile image and set the multiplier value to the desired value:

[image: Set appropriate multiplier]

Now you can also set an aspect ratio for the profile image.

Comment: answer by CoderFrom94 suggested the same thing but it doesn't work.i tested it before.let me show you results.

Comment: this seems almost right scenario! but you should take one 'uiview` with same size of background imageview and set equal width with that view instead of image view!

Comment: question updated and how 'uiview' will effect different than back imageview

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:

1. Provide Aspect Ratio constraint and make the width of the profile pic = width of the screen
   [image]
2. Select the equal width constraint and give the ratio in multiplier
   [image]

Comment: i did but it doesn't work. xcode ignores the aspect ratio constrains because of conflicts with hight and width increase based on background imageview.

Comment: umm, i never gave height and width

Comment: devices doesn't increases sizes in aspect ratio to the previous one.so on bigger device background image doesn't increase with aspect ratio and it's fine for background image but aspect ratio is mandatory for profile image view to make it circular.

Comment: tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 175;
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; this how cell is bring resized for bigger device

Comment: i am not considering background image to adjust the size of the profile pic. the profile pic is center to the view/cell. and it has aspect ratio. I am not giving width and height to the profile pic. But I am giving a constraint saying that the width of the profile pic is equal to the width of the cell. then in the multiplier of that constraint i'm giving the ratio 120:375 (ProfilePicWidth:CellWidth). This will make the profile pic calculate the width based on the width of the cell. and the aspect ratio will calculate the height based on the width. I have used this before and it works.

Comment: If this doesn't solve your issue, I'm afraid I will not be able to help you out. Sorry

Comment: i tried it with content view instead of background image.same result.then i tried it with cell itself.same result

Comment: Please re - read the answer. I'm not setting explicit height and width.

Comment: "But I am giving a constraint saying that the width of the profile pic is equal to the width of the cell. then in the multiplier of that constraint i'm giving the ratio 120:375 (ProfilePicWidth:CellWidth). This will make the profile pic calculate the width based on the width of the cell"

yes i did the same thing.check second last image.

Comment: oh wait, You'll have to make sure the layout is done before applying rounded corners. `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` will help.

Comment: tried layoutIfNeeded() but didn't worked.then another person asked to implement - (void)layoutSubviews in cell.this one worked.